# Exchange - Which metrics are important to monitor / graph

Tags: windows, exchange, monitoring

I have Exchange 2003 on a DC.

Here are the metrics which are available to me in order to make a graph out of them, or simply monitor their status:

```
EXNG: Inbound Connections Current
EXNG: Local Queue Length
EXNG: Local Retry Queue Length
EXNG: Memory Available Bytes
EXNG: Memory Pages\sec
EXNG: Messages Received/sec
EXNG: MSExchangeMTA Submits
EXNG: Page File Usage
EXNG: Pickup Directory Messages Retrieved/sec
EXNG: Remote Queue Length
EXNG: Remote Retry Queue Length
EXNG: Service State - Event
EXNG: Service State - IMAP4
EXNG: Service State - Information Store
EXNG: Service State - Management
EXNG: Service State - MTA Stacks
EXNG: Service State - Network News Transfer Protocol (NNTP)
EXNG: Service State - POP3
EXNG: Service State - Routing Engine
EXNG: Service State - Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)
EXNG: Service State - Site Replication Service
EXNG: Service State - System Attendant
```

So which of these should I keep monitored and why ?

Answer (score 2):

`Service State - Information Store, Routing Engine, System Attendant, and SMTP` will all tell you aggregately, generally, if the Exchange server is running/routing mail.  If you have any POP3 or IMAP4 clients, you'd want to monitor that as well.

`EXNG: Local Queue Length and Local Retry Queue Length` will give you some information as to whether you're experiencing any mailflow issues inbound or outbound.

```
    EXNG: Memory Available Bytes
    EXNG: Memory Pages\sec
    EXNG: Messages Received/sec
    EXNG: Page File Usage
```

Should be monitored for general server health.